# Connection string in parent folder of WCF project is throwing error as The configSource '..\connectionStrings.config' is invalid

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-config, connection-string

We have multiple WCF projects and we want place the all connection strings in one `connectionStrings.config` file and use it from there. For this I have tried the following:

`connectionStrings.config` file in parent folder of all WCF projects (path: `D:\Projects\connectionStrings.config`)

```
<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="Name"   
         providerName="System.Data.ProviderName"   
         connectionString="Valid Connection String;" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

`web.config` file of each WCF Project (path: `D:\Projects\SampleWCFProject\web.config`)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  
<configuration>  
    <connectionStrings configSource="..\connectionStrings.config"/>  
</configuration>
```

But I get this error:

> The configSource attribute is invalid.: The configSource '..\connectionStrings.config' is invalid. It must refer to a file in the same directory or in a subdirectory as the configuration file.

It works if we place the `connectionStrings.config` in same folder as the `web.config` or in a child folder. But that's not what we require.

Can anyone help us with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, we could refer to this file by Adding Existing Item.
[image]
Then switch the “build action” to “content” and “copy to output directory” to “Always” in the property page of the referring file.
[image]
We could choose to add a file to the current project or a link to this file.
[image]
Finally, the file in other directory cannot work may be due to problems with read and write permissions to the file.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.